# Insufficient Permission when using GMAIL AutoForwarding create

Tags: android, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

```
String[] googleSCOPES = {GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS, GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY, GmailScopes.MAIL_GOOGLE_COM};

            GoogleAccountCredential googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    context, Arrays.asList(googleSCOPES))
                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
            googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(appSettings.retrieve(Params.GMAIL_ACCOUNT_NAME));
            com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail mService = new com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), googleAccountCredential)
                    .setApplicationName("StaffConnect")
                    .build();
            ForwardingAddress address = new ForwardingAddress()
                    .setForwardingEmail(emailAddress);
            ForwardingAddress createAddressResult = null;
            try {
                createAddressResult = mService.users().settings().forwardingAddresses()
                        .create("me", address).execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (createAddressResult.getVerificationStatus().equals("accepted")) {
                    AutoForwarding autoForwarding = new AutoForwarding()
                            .setEnabled(true)
                            .setEmailAddress(address.getForwardingEmail())
                            .setDisposition("trash");
                    try {
                        autoForwarding = mService.users().settings().updateAutoForwarding("me", autoForwarding).execute();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

Error:

```
    com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
```

Comment: createAddressResult = mService.users().settings().forwardingAddresses()
                        .create("me", address).execute();
At this point i m getting exception. If trying to retrieve inbox. getting no exception.Only for forwarding, getting so.

Comment: code snippet in code format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "insufficientPermissions"

Means that the current authenticated user does not have the permissions to preform the action you are requesting to use via your application.  Permissions are granted at authentication time and are called scopes.

[Users.settings.forwardingAddresses: create](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/forwardingAddresses/create) request requires authorization with the following scope

Scope

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing

You need to reauthecate your user and request an additional scope.

Comment: Thank u.. its working now after adding seetings.sharing scope and need to handle the exception.

Comment: After adding all the permissions.
still i m getting error.

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Access restricted to service accounts that have been delegated domain-wide authority"
}

Comment: Service accounts cant use Gmail unless its a gsuite email account and you have set up domain wide authority.  Your gsuite admin can help you with that.   https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/delegation  You should open a new question for that error.